# How to indicate outlier in non-normal distribution

Tags: data-transformation, outliers

As I have data with one variable that collect number of pages people read a day. I knew that can not find an outlier by 1.5*IQR as 70% of the data are 1-20. I read that I need to transform my data first but is it possible for one variable to do this with its frequency?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the 2.5% of lowest values and 2.5% of highest values, which is what you do by looking at values that are more than $1.5 \times \text{IQR}$ away from the mean for a normal distribution, you could look at the 2.5% of values that are lowest and 2.5% that are highest.

Whether that is a sensible approach (both for the normal distribution case or for your example) depends on why you want to find such values, of course.

E.g. if you want to find outliers, because you feel that "strange outliers" should be excluded from an analysis, then this is generally a very bad way of going about it - even if there is absolutely nothing wrong with any of your data points, you still exclude 5% of the data, while if all the data is problematic, you still keep 95% of it. In fact, methods that solely look at where some single value lies relative to other values are rarely good for spotting "unusual" data points.